# Create a file on installation of an Android application

Tags: java, android, file, text, installation

I am wondering if (and if so, how) it is possible to create new, empty text file(s) in the app directory when the app first installs. Until now I've always done a:

```
File cart = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "cart.txt");

     if(cart.exists() == false) {
         try {
            cart.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```

But this seems a bit impractical if I need to make about 10 empty text files and it needs to check all those 10 before it starts every time.

I was thinking maybe somewhere in the Manifest but I haven't found any online solutions.

Comment: Why would you use empty file instead of creating them when you need them ?

Comment: @KevinGilles well i just meant in general. They don't need to contain anything they just need to be created upon installation.

Comment: Yes, that's easy. Just create a BroadcastReceiver that listens for an installation event. By the way, why a file? Why couldn't it just be a Preference? That would make it easier for the system to automatically backup. And like Kevin said, it really doesn't need to be created upon installation. It can just be created as needed. When you actually need it, you would just need to check that the file or the Preference doesn't exist before you create it, otherwise you'd just append to it.